# Accepting different Set-implementations as parameter

Tags: java

I am trying to write a function capable of accepting any one of these two objects as parameter:

```
private static TreeSet<String> TREESET = new TreeSet<String>();
private static HashSet<String> HASHSET = new HashSet<String>();
```

I've attempted it like this

```
public static void printSet(Set s) {
  //
}
```

and

```
public static void printSet(Set<String> s) {
  //
}
```

Even while casting the sets at invocation I get an error. What is the proper way to do this?

**Update 1**

I've tried with and without casting:

```
printSet(SET);
printSet((Set) SET);
printSet((Set<String> SET);
```

**Update 2**

The error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: TreeSet cannot be cast to java.util.Set at HashTreeSetClient.main(HashTreeSetClient.java:34)

Comment: How are you invoking the method? Don't use raw types.

Comment: use `public static void printSet(Set<String> s)`

Comment: You're not getting "an error". You're getting a specific error, with a specific error message indicating what and where the problem is. Not reading/posting this error message is your biggest mistake.

Comment: Can you share the error with us?

Comment: Post your exact error message. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: I did indeed read the errors, but it only said I was not allowed to cast TreeSet to Set, HashSet to Set etc.

Comment: HashSet, TreeSet are already Set.. why cast them?

Comment: Post a small but complete and reproducible example.

Comment: You have a custom TreeSet in your project? Or from another library?

Comment: You're probably using a TreeSet class which is not java.util.TreeSet, but another TreeSet class, in another package, that doesn't implement Set. Check your imports. If you have defined your own TreeSet class, then it has to implement Set for the above code to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just use generics as you did.

```
public static <T> void printSet(Set<T> s) {
  //
}
```

Avoid raw types.

---

Or just `Set<String> s` as someone else said.

```
public static void printSet(Set<String> s) {
  //
}
```

`Set` is an interface every class which implement this interface is accepted in the method.

Comment: If you know that you're ever only going to have a `Set<String>`, I don't see the reason to not put that in the method signature.

Comment: What if he changes it?

Comment: Then he's violating his own contract.  From what I'm reading of the OP's post, the contract is that he's going to have `Set<String>`.  If he doesn't, *then* using generics would be more preferable.

Comment: Set is an interface: HashSet is ok, TreeSet is ok, ArrayList is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of the `Set` interface.  Any class that implements `Set` can be regarded *as* a `Set`.

This is why these declarations are legal:

```
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
```

Let's now consider your method:

```
public static void printSet(Set<String> s) {
    // logic
}
```

What this methods tells me is that you don't care about the concrete type of `Set` you're using, but that it is actually something that could be considered a `Set`.

In effect, that means that both of these method calls are legal:

```
printSet(TREESET);
printSet(HASHSET);
```

...and that absolutely no casting is required, since both a `TreeSet` and a `HashSet` implement the `Set` interface.

It is **very important**, however, that the generic type parameter on your sets matches the method signature.

This, for example, would not work:

```
HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
printSet(hashSet); // compilation error
```

If, for some reason, you wanted to accept a `Set` with any generic type parameter on it, you could use this syntax to accomplish that:

```
public static void printSet(Set<?> s) {
    // logic
}
```

The `?` is a **wildcard type**.  It implicitly extends `Object`, and can be used to accept anything as a generic type.